# mysql query always returns false

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the following code would always return false

```
<?php
    require "connectDB.php";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM useraccout WHERE 1";
    $rows = $db->query($query);
```

By false I believe it means that there is something wrong with the statement (can't find what exactly is wrong)

**connectDB.php**

```
<?php

$USERNAME = "root";
$PASSWORD = "";
$DB_NAME = "db";
$SERVER = "localhost";

$db = mysqli_connect($SERVER, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Perhaps the table should be called `useraccount`?

Comment: table useraccount does exist

Comment: have u checked if the credentials are correct and its connecting to database

Comment: yes, database connection is successful

Comment: manually check this query in mysql console `SELECT * FROM useraccout WHERE 1`

Comment: query returned required rows when ran through mysql console

Answer (score 0):

more information are required but from your code here is what i found
1) query = "SELECT * FROM useraccout WHERE 1";

is this **useraccout** right?
or is it not supposed to be **useraccount**

2) please upload a screen shot of your database and useraccout structure

Comment: thanks for finding that typo error, it was supposed to be 'useraccount' and not 'useraccout'

Comment: alright. does that fix the issue? also hope you're aware that it's not necessary to have **where 1** in your sql statement

Answer (score 0):

In you query need to specify the column name to compare

```
<?php
require "connectDB.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM useraccout WHERE column_name=1";
$rows = $db->query($query);
```

Like if you want to compare with id then the query is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM useraccout WHERE id=1";
```

If you want to select all records from table useraccout then the query is

```
SELECT * FROM useraccout;
```